# CSS - Opinions on using many small classes for specific style specifications or a single class with complete style for commonly used elements

Tags: html, css

Sorry for the confusing title, and I apologize if the question is too vague and open ended. The question is as much about good coding style as it is about which will perform better, but I am happy for answers about both if there is a difference.

If I have a multiple instances of a div with the same styling, would it be better to have multiple classes and apply those classes as needed, eg.

```
.blueBackgrnd {
    background-color:blue;
}

.alignCenter {
    text-align:center;
}
smallerSize {
    height:50px;
    width:80%;
    margin: auto
}
largerSize {
    height:100px;
    width:80%;
    margin: auto
}
```

or would it be better to specify one class for a div that will be used multiple times, even if those style properties are repeated multiple times in the CSS file?

```
largeSampleDiv {
  height:100px;
  width:80%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color:blue;
  text-align:center;
}
smallSampleDiv {
  height:50px;
  width:80%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color:blue;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Or a combination of both? Or does it not matter at all?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, try to not have copies of css code if possible. This makes the css file bigger to download for users (impactfull for serious projects). But also, having too many classes can make it harder to work with source code.

this

```
.largeSampleDiv {
  height:100px;
  width:80%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color:blue;
  text-align:center;
}
.smallSampleDiv {
  height:50px;
  width:80%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color:blue;
  text-align:center;
}
```

i would do like this

```
.someDiv {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
}

.small {
  height: 50px;
}
.large {
  height: 100px;
}
```

Also, this page might be of use https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.xml#HTML_Formatting_Rules

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're building something truly gigantic, any effect on performance will be negligible. As far as coding style, here this is really a matter of preference. Pick whichever approach you feel most comfortable with, and be consistent through the project.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to organize your code and what you find a readable code. If you define every formatting in a different style selector, then your code will be immensely large, or you must define them in a separate css file and import them. I personally don't recommend this way of programming, because every div will get a lot of classes and you could get mixed up in the order of implementation.
For a more readable code, try to define the divs as a whole like your second example. Also try to use the width property as high in the order as you can, again for clarity.
And lastly, if you use something like Firebug or an other code debugger, you can walk better through you used styles if you have defined your divs as you mentioned in your second solution. Extra advantage is that you can change and add styles in Firebug to test how you changes look.